# WordPress: can not delete user from wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I need to delete user from my site.

So i go to :-

```
domain.com/wp-admin/users.php
```

And select user to delete and click into `Delete` and go me to page to move user article to another user.

I select another user to move deleted user article to him, But i cannot see delete or any thing to click to delete

Why !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why won’t WordPress let you delete the admin account?

Because under Settings –> General there is a field where you enter an email address.  That email address is the administrative email address contact.  You cannot delete the account that the administrator email account is assigned to.

So, take one more step and switch the admin email address to match the one you setup with the new admin account.  Then, you can go back to the Users screen and delete the admin account without any trouble.

FYI – If you have not created another User account and assigned it administrator rights, you won’t be able to delete the default admin account either.  In WordPress, there always has to be at least one admin account, so you have to create the new admin account first, and then delete the old default administrator account.

****  Make sure you aren't logged in as the same account you are trying to delete too.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your current role is an administrator.[or any high role]

Go to users.php page again, then put cursor over the user you want to delete to make Edit and Delete link come out. And click delete.

here a screenshot https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-u1yQRMUtcMs/VHQce3dcDVI/AAAAAAAAADU/Vvx1mEGcoNs/w1044-h355-no/deluser.png

Comment: yes i am in administrator, and your steps do but problem here http://im50.gulfup.com/GhIqTh.png i don't see delete button

Comment: have you try to chose the option (delete all content, or the other one) to activate the button ?

nb: the button will active when you chose the option